# Unable to call Javascript from Codebehind

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I know my issue is very common and similar types has been asked many times over here, but my problem is somewhat different. I am working on ASP.Net 4.0 web application where on my required page i have ajax toolkit 4 calendar control, toolkitscript manager and few asp controls. Now from that pop up i am doing a save operation on button click. What i want is to close popup window after successful save. Problem is not in saving but after saving , automatically closing the popup screen. I have tried the following ways:

1. RegisterStartUpScriptBlock(this.GetType,"closeForm","return window.close();") and all other required params
2. ClientScript.RegisterStartUpScript()--- alongwith params and with both return window.close(); and window.close() also with self.close();
3. Also i have  under the title tag...

I think i have tried all the ways , i can. I feel i am lost. Please help me out....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your using a script manager on the page...

first create a function to close the calendar in js in your html...

```
 function closeCalendar(){
   ....
}
```

then on the codebehind use this to call that js function

```
string script = string.Format(@"closeCalendar()");

ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(Page), UniqueID, script, true);
```

Comment: ;-( i am not using script manager. Ajax Control Toolkit 3.5+ wont allow asp script managers. I think toolkitscriptmanager is the main reason of such happenings

Comment: maybe some variation of this with toolkitscriptmanager...I am not familiar with that control though or the Ajaxtoolkit 3.5+

Answer (score 0):

If the popup you mean is the AJAX Toolkit Modal Popup, you can just call `popup.Hide();` in codebehind.

If it is a browser window, did you try to remove the `return` part from your code?

Note that `windows.close()` will not work unless the popup is opened via `window.open()`;

Also, did you try to just put the script tag inside PlaceHolder control that is hidden (server-side Visible=false) by default and only shown when you need?

Comment: i believe he is referring to the calendar as the "popup"

Comment: 1. No its a modaldialog , 2. i have tried both way to close window. window.close() and self.close with and without return... please help me i am stucked

Comment: Did you try to just call something like modalDialog.Hide(); in codebehind code?

Comment: Doesn't the ModalDialog extender have an ID? let's say ModalDialogExtender1? Inside the button click event call ModalDialogExtender1.Hide();

Comment: Sorry , its not Modal Dialog extender, it a normal browser modal dialog, that i have opened using window.showmodaldialog()..

Comment: OK, try the other way. Put your code including the script tag inside PlaceHoder control and show this PlaceHolder only in the save.